# AC leaks to laptop, cellphone surface. Feel by finger!

Tags: ac, isolation

I've accidentaly discovered that several mains+battery-powered devices with metallic casing like cellphones, laptops and mp3 players, exhibit a special kind of friction when stroked with a finger. But only as long as the device is connected to mains for recharging! Once running from battery power only, it's smooth again! It's like stroking glass with a wet finger (stick-slip-stick-slip), but more subtle (and doesn't make the noise).

The stick-slip rate appears to be always the same, no matter how light or firm touch you make (unlike with glass&wet finger). I guess it is 50 Hz - AC!

Looks like some charge leaks to the surface of the devices from the power adapter despite proper isolation. Friction ceofficient might be sensitive to the alternating surface charge, hence the stick-slip...

**Question:** Is this a known effect? Does it have a name? Any details?

More info:

- The devices were not faulty. They include Macbook Air and a Cowon mp3 player, among others. I encounter this effect everywhere I go
- You might need to try different parts of your hand to get the stick-slip. Finger pads don't always work for me, finger joints work best. I guess it has to do with sweat.
- If I remember correctly, if I ground myself with my other hand, the effect is gone.

Comment: I use a HP EliteBook 8440P laptop which has a brushed metal wrist rest and lid. I have occasionally experienced this effect when using it, but thought I was imagining it!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a normal effect.  It used to be a lot more common than it is now.  On old tube equipment it was common to tie the chassis to one of the power wires via a large resistor.  The resistor was large enough that you wouldn't get hurt by the current even if you were well grounded and touched the chassis.  Usually you could barely feel it.

One side effect of this is the symptom you describe, depending on which way around the unit was plugged in.  When you are touching something conductive that electrified but with a thin layer of insulation (like paint), you become one plate of a capacitor.  As the voltage on this capacitor goes up and down with the power line, the force between the plates changes too.  This is what you feel as varying friction when you gently slide your hand accross it.  Back in grade school and high school I used to have a shortwave radio like that.

Modern appliances are either explicitly grounded or well insulated.  You are probably touching the external insulation with live line voltage on the other side of it, thereby creating the capacitor.

Comment: Thanks! But laptops and cellphones have an external power adapter... How does AC get to the chassis? Perhaps I feel the AC ripple of the DC input? Or does it go through the insulation all the way from the PA?

Comment: @user: There is probably enough capacitive coupling back to one side of the AC line in the adapter.

Comment: With regards to this, I have a HP laptop with an aluminium case. when on charge from AC (through an earthed plug, uk 3 pin, which is itself in an earthed 3 pin extension lead) there is  the slight vibration felt but also, when I plug in my headphones there is an audible buzz, the rate of the buzz reduces when the screen brightness is lowered and stops completely when I have at least 1 square inch of flesh touching the laptop. Can you think of anything to reduce or remove this buzz?

Comment: @David: Try grounding the case.